# Django: select all A objects that are involved in m2m relationships with any B objects (via B.m2mfield)

Tags: python, django, orm, manytomanyfield

I have a following model:

```
class People(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField

class Recordings(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField
    performers=models.ManyToManyField(People)
```

I need to get all people who are performers, i. e. people who are in performers list of at least one recording.

SQL would be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT people_id FROM recordings_people)
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM recordings_people JOIN people ON recordings_people.people_id=people.id
```

How can I do the same with Django ORM in an elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As easy as 1,2,3 with exclude:

```
People.objects.exclude(recordings=None)
```

Is that elegant enough ? ;)